# Buttons in StackPanel bound to List

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm trying to create a `StackPanel` which will contain `Button`s. Each Button will contain a `string` property from an object from a `List` kept in the ViewModel. After clicking a button a popup control should display. I'm having problems with the StackPanel - it doesn't display my items from the list. What did I do wrong?

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsList}" >
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Content="{Binding Path=ItemName}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: What does your view model look like?

Comment: it's a huge class written by someone else. other items in the xaml file bind to the viewmodel properties without problems. i also tested the above xaml code without binding (put "some text" into button content) and it's not showing correctly either so i presume (though am still not sure) it's a problem with the above code

Comment: I'm pretty sure the problem is not in above xaml code... at least not unless we know your DataContext details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution was that the code was fine but the Button didn't adjust its size according to the Content and I just couldn't see it. After manually hard-coding the Width and Height and Padding set to 0 the contents were finally visible.

`<Button Content="{Binding Path=ItemName}" Width="100" Height="30" Padding="0"/>`

Answer (score 2):

Set the `DataContext` of the `ItemsControl` to an instance of the class where the `ItemsList` property is defined and make sure that there are some items in the collection returned by the `ItemsList` property:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = new YourViewModel();
}
```

Then it should work provided that `ItemsList` and `ItemName` are actually *public properties* and not fields.

```
public List<ContactName> ItemsList { get; } = new List<ContactName>() { new ContactName { Name = "Name01" }, new ContactName { Name = "Name02" }, new ContactName { Name = "Name03" } };
```

Comment: is it enough to bind the DataContext to the viewmodel class, like this
`DataContext="{Binding MyViewModel}"`?

Comment: I've created a completely new project just for a test and have put this xaml code and the list in the code-behind file and it's still not working.

Comment: Then you probably don't set the DataContext. See my edit.

Comment: but i don't have a viewmodel in the new project. it's just the .xaml file and the .xaml.cs file.

Comment: So where is your ItemsList property defined?

Comment: in the test project, it's in the xaml.cs file

Comment: Then the view itself acts as the view model but you must still set the DataContext like this:  `DataContext = this;`

Comment: here's my xaml file:
https://paste.ofcode.org/6Ph6jyyxNdm2FYGiVt49LP. And the xaml.cs: https://paste.ofcode.org/MfbbVfsxxuyb6aNAZanqU6

Comment: Didn't you read my answer? ItemsList must be a property. See my edit.

Comment: And remove this: DataContext="{Binding MainWindow}"

Comment: Sorry, that was supposed to be `ItemsList =>`. I see the buttons in the stackpanel but no content inside. Ie. `Path=Name` doesn't seem to work now.

Comment: Is the Name property of your ContactName class public and being set to a name?